# Is it true that a positive definite bilinear form on a real vector space is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't think the property $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle v,u \rangle$ is satisfied, if the bilinear form is not symmetric.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: yes, symmetry is necessary. (off topic: I am sorry, if I have forgotten that in my previous comment)

Comment: What do you think is the definition of "positive definite?"

Comment: @user251257 Actually I still don't understand the previous question, specifically why $2A(u,u)^\frac 12A(v,v)^\frac 12 \ge A(u,v) + A(v,u)$, where $A$ is a positive definite bilinear form on a real vector space.

Comment: @WillJagy $A(u,u) \gt 0$ if $u \neq 0$ and $A(u,u) = 0$ if $u = 0$? Where $A$ is the positive definite function

Comment: In that case, Nate answered exactly in line with what you expect.

Comment: @user251257 Sorry I still don't understand how this relates to the conclusion...

Comment: @ShiNingSun: If you have another question, or additional question to previous post, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

On the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider the bilinear form defined by
$$\langle (u_1, u_2) , (v_1, v_2) \rangle = u_1 v_1 + u_2 v_2 + u_1 v_2$$
which is clearly not symmetric.

This is "positive definite" in a sense. If $u = (u_1, u_2)$ we have
$$ \langle u,u \rangle = u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_1 u_2.$$
By the AM-GM inequality we have $|u_1 u_2| \le \frac{1}{2}(u_1^2 + u_2^2)$, so 
$$\langle u,u \rangle \ge  u_1^2 + u_2^2 - \frac{1}{2}(u_1^2 + u_2^2) = \frac{1}{2}(u_1^2 + u_2^2) \ge 0.$$

This also shows we have $\langle u,u \rangle = 0$ iff $u=0$.

Note the matrix of this bilinear form is everybody's favorite counterexample matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
whose eigenvalues are all positive, but is neither symmetric nor diagonalizable.
This also shows we have $\langle u,u \rangle = 0$ iff $u=0$.